# Given an element, how do I use jQuery to find out what css classes it has applied to it?

Tags: jquery, web-applications

I have a function that takes an element, and then shows all the other elements that have the same class. I know how to show the elements of a give class, but I dont know how to find out what the class of the given element is. Any ideas? I've looked at the docs quite a bit, but I'm not seeing anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind. `elem.attr("class")` does the trick. I feel kinda silly; sorry to bug you all.

Answer (score 0):

To see all of the classes applied to an element just retrieve the value of the class attribute. This can be accomplished by using the [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method. For a `div` that would look like `div.attr('class')`.